# How do i hide/show iphone buttons only after login in javascript?

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c

Hi i have a javascript login page that is loaded using UIWEBVIEW. How do i ensure that the javascript has login successfully before loading buttons that is relevant to the page?

Answer (score 0):

If I never misread and misunderstand your question, you can try to do something like alert("You have successfully logged in"); first before loading other button? This will help you to check whether if you have successfully logged in. And then continue with the rest of the script.

Do tell me more if I have misunderstand it. =)

Comment: hmmm nice try "KennC".. think u totally misunderstand my question.. cos i want to link it with iphone app.. anyidea dude? :)